# Python: Store CSV data in list or array

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have a csv file storing the number of times students have attempted each question, which has the format as below

```
UserID Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
20     1  2  3  1
21     0  1  2  1
```

I am trying to write a python program to store the data into an array *attempts_count*.

```
attempts_count = numpy.zeros(shape=(2000,200,200))
with open('Question_Attempts_Worksheet_1.csv' , 'r') as csvfile:
        csvfile.readline()  # skip the first line(column title)
        for line in csvfile:
            csv_row = line.split()
            user_id = csv_row[0]
            for question_counter in range(0,4):
                attempts_count[user_id][1][question_counter] += csv_row[question_counter + 1]
```

I expect to obtain `attempts_count[20][1][0]=1`, `attempts_count[20][1][2]=3`, etc.

However, I got an error message saying

> "IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
>   numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid
>   indices".

May I know how should I fix the problem?

Comment: Have you considered importing the `csv` module? It automatically parses your CSV file and allows you to access individual rows and columns without the need to manually parse rows and split by separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve this issue is by `csv` packages, since the file is in `csv` format. This is how it can be done using `csv` packages:

```
attempts_count = numpy.zeros(shape=(2000,200,200))
with open ('Question_Attempts_Worksheet_1.csv' , 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    for row in reader:
        for question_counter in range(0,4):
            attempts_count[int(row[0])][1][question_counter] += int(row[question_counter + 1])
```

However, to proceed from your code, there are at least three problems can be identified in the code.

The first problem is with your `userId`, since you got it from `CSV` file, it is a `string` rather than integer. Try to convert it to `int` before using it:

```
user_id = int(csv_row[0]) #here, get this as integer
```

The second problem is you don't seem to split your CSV row based on `,` separator (while a CSV file's row values are separated by comma). Thus, update also the `string.split(',')` using separator `,`.

```
csv_row = line.split(',') # put , as separator here
```

And lastly, the third problem is similar to the first one. Since you want your `csv_row[question_counter + 1]` to be added to the `attemps_count`, it has to be converted to a number as well:

```
attempts_count[user_id][1][question_counter] += int(csv_row[question_counter + 1])
```

The complete code should look like this:

```
attempts_count = numpy.zeros(shape=(2000,200,200))
with open('Question_Attempts_Worksheet_1.csv' , 'r') as csvfile:
    csvfile.readline()  # skip the first line(column title)
    for line in csvfile:
        csv_row = line.split(',') # put , as separator here
        user_id = int(csv_row[0]) #here, get this as integer
        for question_counter in range(0,4):
            attempts_count[user_id][1][question_counter] += int(csv_row[question_counter + 1])
```